# Why illegal forward reference not variable not found?

Tags: java, static, initialization, declaration

Following code:

```
class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    static int x = 6;
    static double z;
}
```

Will produce error: `Illegal forward reference.`

And,

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(z);
        int z = 8;
    }
}
```

If we use variable before it's declaration inside main() it says:
`Cannot find symbol.`

So, my question is why in case of static blocks it throws: `Illegal forward reference error`?

How does compiler knows variable is declared after that static block? Because static blocks are executed sequentially it should say cannot find symbol

Comment: @defaultlocale No, it's different. Read my question carefully. I am saying If we utilise and then declare variable inside main() it shows variable not found. How both cases are different?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand it first time. I retracted my vote.

Comment: At run time first static variables get memory then static block is executed. So static block gets all the variables even if you have declared them after static block. Method statements are executed sequentially therefore first you have to declare it and then only you can use it.

Comment: @NickSilicon All statements in method are executed sequentially. Methods variable get memory when variable declaration or assignment  statement is executed. So if you try to use a variable before its declaration jvm will not find it in memory and throw Cannot find symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your static initializer is legal. Forward references are allowed on the left hand side of an assignment ([JLS 8.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3)).

```
static {
    x = 10; //this works
}
static int x;

static {
    z = y; //illegal forward reference error.
}
static int y;
static int z;
```

To answer the second part of your question: Why "illegal forward reference" and not "cannot find symbol"?

Cannot find symbol error occurs in a different type of situations:

```
static {
    z = banana; //cannot find symbol
}
static int y;
static int z;
```

Illegal forward reference shows developers that variable is already declared.

**[UPDATE]:** Additional questions raised:

> How does compiler knows variable is declared after that static block? Because static blocks are executed sequentially it should say cannot find symbol

Static blocks are executed sequentially *in runtime*. They are not *compiled* sequentially. Compiler can make as many passes as it wants.

> Why doesn't compiler detect forward references for local variables?

Forward references are only declared for fields. Fields can be accessed in initialization blocks before their declaration. Compiler tries to detect initialization errors.

For example this code is legal:

```
static {
    y = 100;
    z = 200; 
}
static int y;
static int z;
```

This code has an error in initialization sequence:

```
static {
     z = 2*y; //illegal forward reference
}
static int y;
static int z;
```

Local variables can't be accessed before their declaration and this logic doesn't really work for them.

Comment: I read that specification already. And, i wanna know difference in both the situations.

Comment: @NickSilicon I've edited my answer to address the differences between fields and local variables

Comment: default locale: Check  answer of ranjeet. If static blocks are not compiles sequentially, in what order are they compiled. There should be some order, right?

Comment: you are editing my question, I am writing exact errors (keeping cases in mind) which are produced by compiler. And you are editing them.?

Comment: @NickSilicon number and order of [compilation steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-pass_compiler) is not necessarily defined. It might be an implementation detail. Anyway, I don't think that it matters here

Comment: @NickSilicon I just tried to fix code indentation and removed some code irrelevant to your question. Code samples still produce compilation errors. You can rollback [my edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39502850/revisions), but please, keep code formatting intact.

Comment: It does matter, that's why i asked question. I wanna know  thnx

Comment: yea, i am ok with formatting. That was my mistake. It's just that it decreased my repo. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes legal to make a forward reference to an instance variable.  E.g.:

```
class Test {
    private void setXToTen() {  // legal
        x = 10;
    }

    static int x;
    ....
```

That means that in the case of a forward reference to an *instance variable*, the compiler *can* find the symbol.  It's just not legal to do it in certain circumstances.  But a "cannot find symbol" error wouldn't be appropriate--it would be confusing.

Comment: How compiler knows there is declaration after static block. As program runs sequentially, it should not know whether variable is declared after or not.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the program _running_.  Compilers are allowed to look ahead and make multiple passes through the program.  Compilation happens before the program even starts running.

Comment: Then why doesn't it looks in case when we do same thing inside main() method?

Comment: It's not an instance variable, it's a local variable in a method, and the rules are different.  If you want to know why the language designers wrote the rules that way, you'll have to ask them.  They could have allowed local variables to be used before they were declared.  Whatever their reasons were, I'm sure they had a good reason even if we don't understand why.  I've had experience participating in language design discussions (for a different language) and I know they put a lot of thought into every decision they make.

Comment: "Rules" are the statements used by people when they don't know the exact answer. Is it possible to contact language designers? I want to know that the reason. It's ok, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Before compiling your java code into byte code(.class file), the Java compiler optimizes your program. As the static variables are the Class level variables they are globally accessible at compile-time.

The Code optimizer moves all **static variables** from the program at the beginning of the code. Later, all **static blocks** are optimized, **default constructor** is created if any constructor is not present, which calls the super class default constructor, **instance initializer blocks** are optimized if present and so on.

Hence, as the static variables are re-arranged before code compilation you don't any error so called 'Cannot find symbol'.

Below is the actual code:

```
public class Test
{
    static
        {
            x = 10;
        }

    static int x;

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Program starts..");
            System.out.println("Program ends..");
        }

    static int y;
    static
        {
            y = 20;
        }
}
```

Below will be the optimized code:

```
public class Test
{
    static int x,y;
    static
        {
            x = 10;
        }
    static
    {
         y = 20;
    }
    public Test()
        {
            super();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Program starts..");
            System.out.println("Program ends..");
        }
}
```

**Note:** There are lots of optimizing techniques(algorithms) used by java code optimizer, so as to get better performance. The above optimized code is just a re-presentation.
Surely, the optimized code will not be in English language, But it will be in somewhat called human un-readable format.

Comment: LOL. How did you got optimized code? What is Test3()?

Comment: Ok, now it's correct. Firstly, how do you know what will be optimized code?  Secondly, Tell me optimized version of my first code with static block.

Comment: the optimized code is just a representation, java have not revealed how do they optimize the code.

Comment: So, according to you optimized code will have static declaration at the top i.e. before static block. So, why it becomes error?